# Can I set push-options (git push -o "...") in git config?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-push, git-config

Git 2.10 introduced git [push options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/#git-push--o) (`git push -o "my string"`).

Many command line options are configurable, and I was wondering if it was possible for this too. I was not able to find it in [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), but perhaps I'm overlooking it.

So, would it be possible to add a (set of) default push option(s), to have ...

```
git push -o "r=joh.doe"
```

... the default when running ...

```
git push
```

?

<sup>**Context:** 
I am using this with Gerrit to directly assign changes to reviewers ([documentation for reference](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_options) - using compatible syntax `<push-ref>%my_string`). When uploading many changes and working in pairs to review each other's code it would be useful if I can add that person as reviewer at push-time already.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has become configurable in Git 2.16 (quoting [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L27:L28)).

> The "--push-option=" option to "git push" now defaults to a
>   list of strings configured via push.pushOption variable.

So, when applied to Gerrit as for my use case, this should work to add reviewer to `john.doe` and publish draft comments on push time by default.

```
git config --add push.pushOption r=john.doe
git config --add push.pushOption publish-comments
```

Answer (score 2):

This option is not configurable.

You can add the reviewer by [Gerrit's CLI](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-set-reviewers.html) `ssh -p 29418 $USER@$gerrithost gerrit set-reviewers $CHANGE -a $reviewer -p $project` in [Gerrit's hook](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/5d773af4e96249bdbef63fc597e5ee11cf14626e/Documentation/config-hooks.txt) `patchset-created`. The [REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#add-reviewer) `POST /changes/{change-id}/reviewers` can also do the job.

`$reviewer` can be a user or a group which contains one or more users.

Comment: Yes, I know you can set this with the SSH CLI, but that requires to iterate over all created changes in a single push. Server-side hooks are not very elegant for my case as it's a shared server and it should not be hidded that I assigned a reviewer. There's a plugin that can do the same, but it also hides *why* and it requires you to be a project owner.

Comment: @gertvdijk in the documentation you mentioned, https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#reviewers . How about this solution?

Answer (score 1):

What if you just define some aliases to do that?

Ex:

```
alias gp-doe='git push -o "r=joh.doe"'
```

You can use [Git Aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) too.

Comment: Yeah, this could work. Just hoping to have it aware about branches/remotes/repositories like git-config is.