# Can I save a list of reviewers in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

**Gerrit 2.13.8-4-gb79a18cfff-dirty**

I just joined a new project.

Every time I push committed code to Gerrit I need to manually feed it a list of reviewers for my ticket/issue.

Is there any way I can save this list in Gerrit or does the owner of the project need to do that ( how? )

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to have the reviewers plugin installed/configured in your Gerrit server. Only the Gerrit administrators can do that.

See more info about Gerrit plugins [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html).

See more info about the reviewers plugin [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#reviewers).

Comment: Also the Owners plugin offers this, and perhaps more plugins can add reviewers automatically. Anyway, I think my answer regarding a client side option could be more generally applicable when working with Gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set push options in your Git configuration to automatically add reviewers for every push. For example, to add `john.doe` as reviewer for every change pushed from this repository:

```
git config --local --add push.pushOption r=john.doe
```

The above approach requires Git 2.16+, though. See also [Can I set push-options (git push -o “…”) in git config?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48319220/1254292).

If you are still on an older Git version locally, you could pass the option via a Bash or Git alias or even use the old syntax for push options, e.g.:

```
alias gpr 'git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%r=john.doe'
```